# AnyLogic: Dynamically change color of Rectangle when agent is in machine

Tags: colors, simulation, anylogic, agent

Attached is a snippet of my implementation. The machine is a resource and modeled as an agent. When clicking on the rectangle, I am redirected to the agent (the resource machine). What happens in this machine is irrelevant to my problem.
How can I change the color of the rectangle dynamically?

1. Simple: if there is an agent in the machine, I want it to show the state yellow. If it is not in, the rectangle should show green.
2. More complex: If there are few agents in the machine, I want the rectangle to be green and the more agents there are at the current time, the redder the rectangle should turn. So specify a color gradient, which changes according to the given number of agents in the machine.

Can someone help me here? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dynamic properties of the rectangle shape for its fill color.

1. Either check via code or use a boolean flag in your machine `isOccupied`. Set it to true if someone enters, and false upon exit. Then, you can change the color as below:
   [image]
2. A bit more complex, you need to define your own function. Switch the boolean variable from above to an integer `numVisitors`. When someone enters, add to it, when someone leaves, you reduce it by 1. Create the function `getMyColor(int numVisitors)`returns a `Color` and take as an input the `numVisitors`. You need to code the actual gradient yourself, there surely is some Java code online to help with it. Last, let your rectangle color be defined by the function as below:
   [image]

Comment: Hey Benjamin, thank you very much for your help!
I still have the problem with the first point, that i can't properly assign my variable to the state when an agent enters the system.

Comment: The following has occurred to me as a possible solution: 
I would create a double variable and create a restricted area. I would then feed the variable with the following code: 

if (restrictedAreaStart.entitiesInside() > 0) { 
 true; }
 
else { 
 false; }

And the Fill Color just as you described it. But unfortunately it does not work. Do you know a better way?

Comment: if you use the restricted area, just change the logic in the rectangle fill color to `myRestrictedAreaStart.entitiesInside() > 0 ? red : green` :)

Comment: check the help to understand these dynamic fields, they constantly recalculate themselves, quite powerful

Comment: Please flag the answer as "useful", helps others with similar problems in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: I'm sorry Benjamin, but I can't vote yet, but will do so when I have enough reputations. :)

Comment: I have another question: due to the development of my model, I now want to embed more features in the coloring. In the Java source code of my class, I saw that color is integrated as a method call with the input color as a word (that's why no semicolon in your code). 
Is there a way around this? Otherwise a more complicated coloring would not be possible. 

I have attached an example here in this screenshot how I could imagine it, however I get some errors because semicolons are missing and I have not declared the variables. Can you help me? 

https://imgur.com/a/Fa1cKj7

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum :)

Comment: Okay I'm sorry, will do! Thanks for the advice.